# Interaction with a continuously running subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, popen3

Python 3.7

test.py

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python3.7', 'mirror.py'],
                        bufsize=0,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

proc.stdin.write('1234\n'.encode())
proc.stdin.flush()
print(proc.stdout.read())
```

mirror.py

```
np = input()
print(np[::-1])
```

So I want to run mirror.py continuously and interract (send message to and reach ansver from) them more than one time. But when I try to add While True loop to mirror.py I got stuck: test.py not showing anything I try to change input and print to sys.stdin/out.read/write and got the same I try to change loop to multiply input/print pairs and got the same

I think I need to stop reading from stdout (maybe send something special from mirror.py after mirrored input) Can any one help me to reach the goal?

Thx

Comment: Why are you running Python as a subprocess of Python? You get a lot better control by using multiprocessing or threading and keeping it in a single program.

Comment: You need loops in both test.py and mirror.py.

Comment: @tripleee
>Why are you running Python as a subprocess of Python?
This is a concept of wrapper, that would start different engins and propogate tasks to it.

Comment: @martineau
>You need loops in both test.py and mirror.py.  

start subproc in loop is not an option

Comment: You can use multiprocessing here. Please refer the below link. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: IDK how to use formatting and can't insert solution. But I fix it.
import sys
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    sys.stdin.flush()
    a = input()
    sys.stdout.write(f'{a[::-1], i}\n')